# Feathering NSView Opacity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, drawing, nsview

I wish to have an NSView with one side of it fading out to an alpha of 0.0f. What is the best practice for doing this? This effect is similar to that of feathering a selection in Photoshop or Pixelmator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your view a backing store layer (check out the `NSView` `wantsLayer` and `layer` properties).  Make a CAGradientLayer and set its your backing store layer's mask.

Comment: Will a layer-backed view take anti-aliasing off my text?

Comment: I don't know.  Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way to do this is to draw a gradient and, in your view's `drawRect:`, call `CGContextClipToMask()` to use the gradient image as a mask.

Answer (score 0):

Make a .png image that starts from transparent and fades out to the color that you want to your NSView to fade out to.

Then add an image element that covers all the NSView and display the .png image that you made before.

That should do it.

Comment: I thought of this but it wasn't the approach I was really looking for